# How to parse xml file in Lua?

Tags: xml, lua

There is a simple xml file which I want to parse using Lua. What lua xml library should I use? I tried [xml lib by Lubyk](http://doc.lubyk.org/xml.html) but it didn't work for me.

Here is what I did:
`$ sudo luarocks install xml`

Tried to import the module:
`require("xml")`

Ended up with:

```
error loading module 'xml.core' from file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/xml/core.so':
    /usr/lib/lua/5.3/xml/core.so: undefined symbol: lua_tonumber
lua: /usr/share/lua/5.3/xml/init.lua:31: attempt to call a nil value (field 'Parser')
stack traceback:
    /usr/share/lua/5.3/xml/init.lua:31: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    lua_doc_reader.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

So, what is the defacto xml reading library in Lua?

Comment: Try [my lxml](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#lxml), which is based on expat.

Comment: I am sorry but after "By far, the easiest way to add libraries to Lua is to dynamically load them. ", I stopped reading.

Comment: There is no "dynamic loading" in my post, I am looking for a simple way to read xml. Also, do you seriously think that somebody will go through editing the Makefile and then compile lua to support dynamic loading only to install one of the libs from your website? I really appreciate your help but this is not the way ppl will use your lib collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after trying to use various xml libs, the one that worked for me was **xmlreader**.

`$ sudo luarocks install lua-xmlreader`

Then, according to the xmlreader docs:

```
require('xmlreader')

fhandle = io.open("temp.xml", 'r')
data = fhandle:read("*a")

local r = assert(xmlreader.from_string(data))
while (r:read()) do
  local leadingws = ('    '):rep(r:depth())
  if (r:node_type() == 'element') then
    io.write(('%s%s:'):format(leadingws, r:name()))
    while (r:move_to_next_attribute()) do
      io.write((' %s=%q'):format(r:name(), r:value()))
    end
    io.write('\n')
  end
end
```

The code above, prints out the xml structure of your document.